# How can I use polymorphism to make a method that instantiates objects and then fill an ArrayList with them efficiently?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, polymorphism, subclass

I have an assignment that requires me to write several classes, and now I am finally writing the class with the main method in it. Here are the instructions for this class:

---

For the AccountDriver class, create:

1. The file name for this class should be: AccountDriver.java.
2. A main() method.
3. An ArrayList to store 10 objects of either the Savings or Checking class. Use 2% (.02) for the 
   savings account rate. Use account numbers 100 through 109. Use initial balances of 1000 through
4. A method called buildSavings() that instantiates Savings objects through the use of 
   polymorphism. This method should create a new Savings object and fill in the corresponding data 
   through the use of a constructor call. The objects' types should be of type Account but they should be
   instantiated as type Savings (polymorphic).
5. Think about how this should be tested. Design test data that thoroughly tests the functionality of the 
   class and inheritance hierarchy. At a minimum, you should test 5 object instantiations.
6. Once instantiated, this method should store the savings accounts in the ArrayList created above. 
   Store the savings accounts in ascending order.

---

I have already writting the Account, Checking, and Savings classes, all of which have two constructors including the default (that I wrote out). Checkings and Savings both extend Account. Account has two protected values, accountNum(int) and accountBal(double). Savings has added a private double named interestRate. Account and Savings have getters and setters for their values. Checking and Savings have @Override (a new concept for me) toString methods. They are simple classes, really.

Right now I am having issues with this AccountDriver class since all the things I am supposed to be doing are generaly new.

I want to start by making that buildSavings() method, but the instructions on creating an object whos type is Account but is instantiated as Savings is really weird. I have never done that before and I don't understand how I am suppose to write that - using instanceOf maybe? That is also new-ish to me.

I am also confused by the fact that all the information that needs to be put into the Savings objects is included in the ArrayList instructions, so I just wrote this:

```
ArrayList<Savings> savingsAccount = new ArrayList<>();
```

But I don't think that's right now, since I am supposed to be making this buildSavings() method. So, am I going to be calling that method when making the ArrayList? Or is that way after I create the ArrayList? Do I use the buildSavings() method when adding objects to the ArrayList using .add?

This is all I could muster up for the buildSavings() method. I obviously don't know how the whole polymorphism thing works, and my book isn't really clear on any particular syntax.

```
    public Account buildSavings () {
    Savings account = new Savings (100, 0.2);

    // what will I be returning? Why can't I put a for loop here to fill up the objects?
    // The two parameters are 100 (accountNum) and 0.2 (interest rate). How do I 
    // set the account balance when the default constructor takes no parameters and
    // the instructions specify that the second contructor only take the account number and
    // interest rate as parameters?
}
```

If someone could clarify these weird instructions by giving me an example, that would be great. I will be emailing my teacher as well, but it's the weekend now so I won't be able to actually go in for office hours.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although being a bit ambiguous the directions use more plural than singular, so I suspect your teacher wants you to create the array within the buildSavings method. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 100; i <= 109; ++i) {
    accounts.add(new Savings(i, 0.2));
}
return accounts;
```

The Savings class meets everything what is expected from the Account class and that is why it is OK to use Savings class everywhere where Account class is expected. Note that the vice versa argument does not hold. Savings class has an interest rate which Account class does not have.
To find out more about polymorphism you can take a look at [oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) or simply google for it.